# QGIS Raster Statistics For Values Intersecting A Line Feature Vector Layer

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal-rasterize, rasterstats

Using QGIS 3.16.10 I want to obtain statistics for values in a raster layer that intersect with a line feature shapefile. I have tried using v.rast.stats but generate only 0 values.

Answer (score 2):

I buffered the line vector layer and ran the "Zonal Statistics" geoprocessing tool.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz this is my answer